# My proof of: Every convergent real sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Is my proof correct?

---

Let $(x_n)_{ n \in \mathbb{N} }$ be a real sequence.

$\textbf{Definition 1.}$
$(x_n)$ is $\textit{convergent}$ iff
there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that,
for every $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\varepsilon > 0$,
there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that,
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n > N$,
we have $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$.

$\textbf{Definition 2.}$
$(x_n)$ is a $\textit{Cauchy sequence}$ iff,
for every $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\varepsilon > 0$,
there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that,
for every $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m,n > N$,
we have $|x_m - x_n| < \varepsilon$.

$\textbf{Theorem.}$
If $(x_n)$ is convergent,
then it is a Cauchy sequence.

$\textit{Proof.}$
We assume that $(x_n)$ is convergent.
It remains to prove that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.
To that end, we consider Definition 2.
Let $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\varepsilon > 0$.
It remains to prove that
there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that,
for every $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m,n > N$,
we have $|x_m - x_n| < \varepsilon$.
Therefore, our next step is to choose $N$.
Since $(x_n)$ is convergent, by Definition 1,
there are $x \in \mathbb{R}, N' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that,
for every $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n' > N'$,
we have
\begin{equation*}
  |x_{n'} - x| < \varepsilon / 2. \qquad\qquad (\textbf{Property 1})
\end{equation*}
We choose $N := N'$.
It remains to prove that,
for every $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m,n > N$,
we have $|x_m - x_n| < \varepsilon$.
Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $m,n > N$.
Obviously, by Property 1, we have both
$|x_m - x| < \varepsilon / 2$ and
$|x_n - x| < \varepsilon / 2$.
Therefore, we have
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    |x_m - x_n| & =   |x_m - x_n + 0| \\
                & =   |x_m - x_n + (x - x)| \\
                & =   |(x_m - x) + ( - x_n + x)| \\
                & \le |x_m - x| + | - x_n + x|
                  && | \text{ by subadditivity of abs. val.} \\
                & =   |x_m - x| + |x_n - x|
                  && | \text{ by evenness of abs. val.} \\
                & < \varepsilon / 2 + \varepsilon / 2 \\
                & = \varepsilon.
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}
Thus, by transitivity,
$|x_m - x_n| < \varepsilon$.
QED

Comment: Looks fine to me.