# My Proof: Every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a real sequence.

$\textbf{Definition 1.}$
$(x_n)$ is $\textit{convergent}$ iff
there is an $x\in\Bbb R$ such that,
for every $\varepsilon\in\Bbb R$ with $\varepsilon>0$,
there is an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that,
for every $n\in\Bbb N$ with $n>N$,
we have $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$.

$\textbf{Definition 2.}$
$(x_n)$ is a $\textit{Cauchy sequence}$ iff,
for every $\varepsilon \in\Bbb R$ with $\varepsilon > 0$,
there is an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that,
for every $m,n\in\Bbb N$ with $m,n > N$,
we have $|x_m - x_n| < \varepsilon$.

$\textbf{Theorem.}$
If $(x_n)$ is convergent,
then it is a Cauchy sequence.

*Proof*: Since $(x_n)\to x$ we have the following for for some $\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2 > 0$ there exists $N_1, N_2 \in \Bbb N$ such for all $n_1>N_1$ and $n_2>N_2$ following holds $$|x_{n_1}-x|<\varepsilon_1\\ |x_{n_2}-x|<\varepsilon_2$$
So both will hold for all $n_1, n_2 >\max(N_1, N_2)=N$, say $\varepsilon = \max(\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2)$ then $$|x_{n_1}-x-(x_{n_2}-x)|<\varepsilon\\\implies |x_{n_1}-x_{n_2}|<\varepsilon$$
Hence all convergent sequences are Cauchy.

Is this proof correct? I also saw this question and copied some of the content(definition and theorem) from there.https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1105255

Comment: No.  The proof has a fatal error.  Neither of the definitions say the an epsilon exist that does what you want.  They both say *ALL* epsilons do what you want.  So you certainly can't say let epsilon = max.  You *must* define epsilon *first*.

Comment: Yes, I see that now.

Comment: Perhaps I was too harsh.  You proof is flawed in that looks for a specific rather than starting with the general.  But the mechanics for the most part is good.  So the proof is salvageable if you redo it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Idea is right, but the execution misses out on a couple of points.

> So both will hold for all $n_1, n_2 > \max(N_1, N_2)=N$, say $\epsilon = \max(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$

Technically $\,\epsilon\,$ is a given, you don't get to choose it.

> then $\quad|x_{n_1}-x-(x_{n_2}-x)|<\epsilon \quad\implies\quad |x_{n_1}-x_{n_2}|<\epsilon$

The RHS does not follow from the stated premise that $\,|x_{n_1}-x| \lt \epsilon_1\,$ and $\,|x_{n_2}-x| \lt \epsilon_2$. At best, from the triangle inequality:

$$
|x_{n_1} - x_{n_2}| = |(x_{n_1}-x)-(x_{n_2}-x)| \le |x_{n_1}-x| + |x_{n_2}-x| \lt \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2
$$

To fix it, just assume $\,\epsilon\,$ is given, choose $\,\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\epsilon / 2\,$, then proceed along the same line.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the implication written *does* follow, but the implicit implication $$|x_{n_1} - x| < \epsilon_1 \text{ and } |x_{n_2} - x| < \epsilon_2 \implies |x_{n_1} - x - (x_{n_2} - x)| < \epsilon$$ is not valid.

Comment: @TheoBendit can you please explain with a counter example why this implication isn't valid

Comment: @TheoBendit Fair point, thank you. Updated the answer to make that clear.

Comment: Alright I got it, thanks to all you guys.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar I know you just got it, but here's the counterexample I was just about to post: Take $\epsilon_1 = \epsilon_2 = 1$ (hence $\epsilon = 1$), $x = 0$, $x_{n_1} = 0.75$, and $x_{n_2} = -0.75$.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Or, if you really wanted to annoy someone, you could take $\epsilon_1 = \epsilon / \pi$ and $\epsilon_2 = (1 - 1/ \pi)\epsilon\,$ ;-) Point being that there is not a *unique* choice of $\epsilon_{1,2}$ in such cases, but you'd usually go with what's the easiest, most obvious one.

Comment: LOL. I really love this site.

Answer (score 6):

It should not be that for some $\epsilon_{1},\epsilon_{2}>0$. Rather, one fixes an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, and we find $N_{1},N_{2}$ such that $|x_{n_{1}}-x|<\epsilon/2$ and $|x_{n_{2}}-x|<\epsilon/2$ for all $n_{1}>N_{1}$, $n_{2}>N_{2}$.

For all $n_{1},n_{2}>\max(N_{1},N_{2})$, then $|x_{n_{1}}-x_{n_{2}}|=|x_{n_{1}}-x-(x_{n_{2}}-x)|\leq|x_{n_{1}}-x|+|x_{n_{2}}-x|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$.

Actually just one $N$ for which $|x_{n}-x|<\epsilon/2$, $n\geq N$ is enough.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, then you actually only need one $N$ such that $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon/2$ for all $n > N$, right? There is no need for $N_1$ and $N_2$ and taking the max.

Comment: Yes, true, I just followed what OP wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution, but take into account that i am just a student.

Let $(a_n)$ be a convergent sequence, and let $L$ be its limit. Then, for any $\epsilon/2 > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n - L| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n \geq N$.

Now, let $m,n \geq N$. Then, by the triangle inequality, we have:

$$|a_n - a_m| = |(a_n - L) + (L - a_m)| \leq |a_n - L| + |L - a_m| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

Thus, $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.